# System.BadImageFormatException when installing a service

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, badimageformatexception

I have created an exe using exe4j (chose to create a service )
I am running installutil from v2.0 .net framework library using

```
 installutil c:\...\myExe
```

and I get

the module was expected to contain an assembly manifest - badimageformatexception

How can I solve this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InstallUtil is an installer for NET created services.
I doubt that it can install a service created with exe4j.

I will try using sc.exe

[See references](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192)